# how to make .jar file in Eclipse MARS

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm learning Hadoop under VMware now.(win7, 64) Due to some reason, I can't convert a .java file to .jar file under virtual machine, so I tried to create .jar file under Eclipse.

I'm currently using Eclipse MARS(4.5.1). I need to download something about fat jar, but I can't find it online.

My colleague copied his Eclipse software to me. It is already installed, so I copied the whole package. It is Eclipse Kepler. So I am running two Eclipse software on my computer now. will this cause some problem? (I saved projects seperately)

I can do the convert .jar file thing correctly on Eclipse Kepler now. But I still want to use MARS and delete the extra Eclipse.

thank you !

Comment: what steps did u follow? do right click project export jar!

Comment: in my Eclipse MARS, there is no "export jar" option....

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the "Fat JAR" eclipse plugin.
Fat jar is a jar which contains all the classes used by the project including their referenced dependencies.
The plugin can enable the creation of such a jar.
In your case, however, Eclipse "Mars" & Eclipse "Kepler" include this functionality. The trick is to get to it...
Here's what you do in order to export a Fat JAR:

1. Right-click on the required Project and select "***Export...***" ***-->*** "***Runnable JAR file***".
2. Select the option which **extracts** libraries and specify the destination JAR file.
3. Launch configuration is used to execute this JAR with a predefined "Main" class (this is the "Runnable" part...) using "java -jar file.jar".
   If you don't plan to - it won't matter.
4. (Optional) You can also "Save as ANT script" which, well..., generates XML ant script as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

select project

```
select Export

Expand the Java node and select JAR file. Click Next

In the JAR File Specification page, select the resources that you want to export in the Select the resources to export field
```

. 
    Select the appropriate checkbox to specify whether you want to Export generated class files and resources or Export Java source

or go to http://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/how-to-create-jar-file-in-eclipse